# how to insert many transactions of similar detail in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to enter 100 transactions into a sql server DB that have the same address and phone number but a different name.
Thanks

Ok lots of negative reaction from the happy people so

I want to insert 100 transaction all the same name & address but different PO box. so my insert would look something like this .

```
Insert into PEOPLE (PO_BOX, NAME , ADDRESS) 
VALUES ('100501', 'MICHAEL COLLINS', 'MBEAL NA BLATH')
```

How can I do this while keeping the same name and address but incrementing the po box from 100501 to 100600 . The po box is not the primary key as there is already an index key.

THanks

Comment: Yes. Haven't tried only have a few minutes of a window.

Comment: Just specify 100 INSERTS with the same address, phone, but different name .. could get fancy with MERGE or otherwise but it's not needed. It seems sort of odd to want to duplicate an address/phone hundreds of times, though. (How the INSERTS are created and DRY'ed up depends upon what's being used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names are stored in another table then you can do the following:

```
insert into test (id, name, address, phonenumber)
select id, name, '123 test dr', '12345678'
from names

select * from test
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7398f/2) with Demo

Based on your edit, you will do the following:

```
declare @recNum int = 0

while @recNum < 100
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO people (po_box, name, address)
    SELECT 100501 + @recNum, 'MICHAEL COLLINS', 'MBEAL NA BLATH'

    set @recNum = @recNum + 1
  END


select *
from people
```

See [SQL fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e03e7/3)

Comment: @Axle see my edit you will do the same thing as the initial answer except you will replace the names table with your people table.